# Implement own collection in C# but need to modify the IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable

I found a great article illustrate IEnumerable and IEnumerator

https://programmingwithmosh.com/csharp/ienumerable-and-ienumerator/

below is the source code:

```
public class List : IEnumerable
{
    private object[] _objects;

    public List()
    {
        _objects = new object[100];
    }

    public void Add(object obj)
    {
        _objects[_objects.Count] = obj;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ListEnumerator();     //region 1
    } 

    private class ListEnumerator : IEnumerator 
    {
       private int _currentIndex = -1;
       public bool MoveNext()
       {
          _currentIndex++;
           return (_currentIndex < _objects.Count); 
       }
       public object Current
       {
         ...
       }
       public void Reset()
       {
           _currentIndex = -1;
       }
    }
}
```

I found some mistakes in this article, probably some typos such as `_objects.Count` should be `_objects.Length`
but one fundamental problem is: How can you get access `_objects` in ListEnumerator?
So I guess I need to pass 'this' in region 1

```
 public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
 {
    return new ListEnumerator(this);
 }
```

and modify ListEnumerator as:

```
private class ListEnumerator : IEnumerator 
{
   private int _currentIndex = -1;
   IEnumerable aggregate = null;
   public ListEnumerator(IEnumerable param)
   {
      aggregate  = param
   }

   public bool MoveNext()
   {
      _currentIndex++; 
      return (_currentIndex < aggregate.Count);   //important region
   }
   public object Current
   {
      //don't worry about the boundary check/exceptions
     get
     {
         return aggregate[_currentIndex];  //important region
     }
   }
...
}
```

In order to do this, IEnumerable also needs to be like

```
interface IEnumerable 
{
   IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
   int Count{get;}
   object this[int itemIndex]{set;get;}
}
```

but we all know `IEnumerable` only have one method `GetEnumerator()` that needs to be implemented. So how can we do this, can anybody modify the code to make it work?

Comment: your question is not clear enough, what do you mean by 'make it work'? what's not working? can you also paste how you will consume your custom defined collection?

Comment: What if you change constructor of `ListEnumerator` to accept an array of objects and then use it like `new ListEnumerator(this._objects);`?

Comment: @LeiYang   the problem is, to make it work, you need to have more methods in IEnumerable interface, but it only have one method there

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya, never realized that nested classes cannot access private members of the surrounding class

Comment: i have this concern because why do you trust that linked artical is correct(you've already seen compiling errors such as  `Count`), if i need some custom collection, why not find msdn articles first? so explain if you have some special requirements.

Comment: @amjad you will need to pass in a reference. Actually you can look at microsoft's implementation and they are doing something similar (passing a reference): https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d3661cf752ff3f44

Comment: The article looks OK, but the code presented just isn't complete. The big thing missing is a link to a Github or zip file with the working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the code of the article which you are referring.

`_objects` is a private member of class `List` so it can not be accessed outside of the class, even from the innterclass of `List`.

Even if you make `_objects` public, it can not be accessed without creating an object of `List` class.

Also there is no way `IEnumerable` interface can be modified.

I would suggest following two approaches.

**Approach 1**

Change `ListEnumerator` class constructor to accept an an object of `List` class

```
private class ListEnumerator : IEnumerator 
{
    private List _list;
    public ListEnumerator(List list)
    {
        this._list = list;
    }
    private int _currentIndex = -1; 

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        _currentIndex++;

        return (_currentIndex < this._list._objects.Length); 
    }

    public object Current
    { 
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return this._list._objects[_currentIndex];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _currentIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

You also need to remove `private` from the declaration of `_objects` in `List` class.
And pass `this` to ListEnumerator constructor.

```
public class List : IEnumerable
{
    object[] _objects;

    public List()
    {
        _objects = new object[100];
    }
    //Other code of List class.

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
       return new ListEnumerator(this);
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**

Change `ListEnumerator` class constructor to accept an array of objects.

```
private class ListEnumerator : IEnumerator 
{
    private object[] _objects;
    public ListEnumerator(object[] objects)
    {
        this._objects = objects;
    }

    private int _currentIndex = -1; 

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        _currentIndex++;

        return (_currentIndex < this._objects.Length); 
    }

    public object Current
    { 
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return this._objects[_currentIndex];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _currentIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

And use it as following in List class.

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
   return new ListEnumerator(this._objects);
}
```

Comment: I was actually also thinking the approach 2 before I posted this question. Just one last question, do it mean that every collection. array, ArrayList, List, they all have a nested private class(to implement the IEnumerator) in the source code? (this question is actually not correct, becuase only array needs to implement IEnumerator, other collections actually contain array object, which can get an IEnumerator by calling `arrayObject.GetEnumerator();`

Comment: You are right...  All the collection classes do not need specific Enumerator implementations if they can just use Array.GetEnumerator(). But I am not sure of how Microsoft had gone about it. It is also safe to assume that every collection uses array as internal collection to store the data. You can look at the Microsoft code https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Collections

Comment: I mean,  It is also NOT safe to assume that every collection uses array as internal collection to store the data. That would require specific implementations for IEnumerator for difference collections.